# jQuery UI Datepicker - Date of Birth - Year not being selected correctly

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am having a problem getting users to select the correct year in their date of birth on a form. I have set the yearRange and changeYear options but it still defaults to 2011 when selected.

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/allyreid/H94cc/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I moved the yearRange selection into the `datepicker` options, and then added `changeYear`.

```
// UI Date Picker
$(".datepicker").datepicker({

    showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "/images/calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    yearRange: '1910:2010',
    changeYear: true
});
```

Comment: just read that my solution will only set the range of years in the dropdown, it wont stop you from going beyond those dates, if you toggle to the next month, may be an idea to used both `Matt` and My suggestion in conjunction with each other?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to use the changeMonth option using a dropdown select instead of the left and right arrows, when this is enabled it defaults to 2011.

Comment: if you set a `defaultDate: new Date(1910,0,1)` that will get you into your date range. not sure how you can hide the arrows. look at `hideIfNoPrevNext` if you are setting the min and max as suggested by Matt, once you hit the end of the range the next and previous buttons wont work. see my update to your jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/H94cc/14/

Comment: Thanks for your help here. The problem that remains is that if the user selects month then day it inserts in the year 2011 by default. They have to select month, year then day for it to be added correctly. How can I change the order they enter the date?

Comment: Only if they are in 2011? sorry, you're confusing me now... as a user I change the month to May, select the year as 1980 and then choose 21. That will enter the date as 21/05/1980. The demo I added in my above comment will default to 1/1/1910.  Only if get to 2011 would the year be added as 2011. An alternative is: give them 3 dropdown one for month, one for year and another for day. That might be the only way you can be sure they have given you want you neeed.

Comment: yearRange: "-120:+0" gives you a dynamic year range from the current year back 120 years.

Answer (score 5):

Did you read the documentation? http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max It even gives an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/H94cc/4/

http://jsfiddle.net/H94cc/13/

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(1910,0,1),
    maxDate: new Date(2010,0,1),
    yearRange: '1910:2010' ,
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true
});
```